# How to remove file from list after successful upload?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

This is my first question on StackOverflow so please bear with my noobness. 
I am writing a Cordova app with Ionic Framework and I am trying to upload multiple files from the camera to a server while displaying the uploaded files in a list and showing the progress for each of them. But I can't seem to figure out how to delete the files from the display list after a successful upload. I am trying to use the `ID` of the File I get after I push it to the array, but those seem to be incorrect sometimes. E.g. the `ID` in the progress event is different than in the success event and therefore I am removing the wrong file from the list or sometimes no file.

```
      $scope.choosePic = function() {
       window.imagePicker.getPictures(
          function(results) {
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                  console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
                  onSuccess(results[i]);
              }
          }, function (error) {
              console.log('Error: ' + error);
          }
      );
    }

    $scope.delete = function ( item ) {
      $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    }

    var onSuccess = function(FILE_URI) {
        console.log(FILE_URI);
        $scope.picData = FILE_URI;

        var filename = $scope.makeid();
        var length = $scope.items.push({name: filename,  image: $scope.picData, progress:0 });
        $scope.$apply();
        send($scope.picData,filename,length);



    };
    var onFail = function(e) {
        console.log("On fail " + e);
    }
    send = function(imagedata,filename,length) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        var url = window.localStorage['URL'];
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
        options.headers = {Connection: "close"};

        var params = {};
        params.APIKEY = window.localStorage['APIKEY'];
        params.DEVICEID = device.uuid;
        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();


        var ID = length -1;


        ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
          if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
            if(!(typeof $scope.items[ID] == 'undefined')){
              $scope.items[ID].progress=perc;
              $scope.$apply();
              console.log($scope.items[ID].name + "Upload progress: " + perc);
            }
            } else {

            }
        };
        function onUploadSuccess(r) {
            //alert("ID = " + ID + " Code = " + r.responseCode + "Response = " + r.response + "Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
            //alert($scope.items[ID].name);
            console.log("ID = " + ID + " Code = " + r.responseCode + "Response = " + r.response + "Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
            $scope.items.splice(ID, 1); // remove uploaded image from list
            $scope.$apply();
        }
        function onUploadFail(error) {
          alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
          //console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
          // console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        }

        options.fileName=filename+".jpg";
        ft.upload(imagedata, encodeURI(url), onUploadSuccess, onUploadFail, options);

    }


});
```

I know this code probably rather clumsy but this the first time I am working with AngularJS and Cordova and the likes of it. Thanks for your help in advance.